# Why won't my width adjust for the container?

Tags: html, css

I have a container that won't respond to different a different width. I'd like it to be at 80% size of the screen but its completely unresponsive. When no width is defined, it looks like this: [image]

When i set `width: 80vh`, it looks like this:[image]

I've tried to set `display: inline` with no luck, I've made sure the class name isn't accidentally repeated elsewhere in my project and I've tried adjust the `margin` so that left and right margins are at zero but nothing will work. Here is my CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(232, 234, 246);
  padding: 6vh 0vh 4vh;
}

.container {
  width: 80vh;
  margin: 4vh auto 4vh;
  padding: 2vh 5vh 2vh;

  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.bio-pic {
  float: left;
  margin: 2vh 2vh 1vh;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.container h2 {
  margin-top: 2vh;
}

.container p {
  margin-left: 2vh;
}
```

And here is the component:

```html
const Bio = () => {
  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <div className='container' id='about'>
        <Image className='bio-pic' src={profile} alt='casey' />
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <p>
          I am a full-stack web developer, passionate about turning ideas into
          reality. Experienced with front-end and back-end development, I enjoy
          the logical puzzles that come with software engineering and take pride
          in writting elegant, dry code. I am excited to apply the skills I've
          built as a developer in a challenging environment where I can grow as
          a professional and be a positive impact as a team member.
          <br />
          <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your container. You set `vh` (viewport height) unit instead of `vw` (viewport width):

```
.container {
  width: 80vw; /*** HERE was vh instead of vw ***/
  margin: 4vh auto 4vh;
  padding: 2vh 5vh 2vh;

  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

I also saw that almost everywhere you were setting padding, margin, etc. with `vh` you might want to set `vw` for (left, right) instead.

**I changed the `className` to `class` to make snippet work for the demo.**

### DEMO:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(232, 234, 246);
  padding: 6vh 0vh 4vh;
}

.container {
  width: 80vw; /*** HERE was vh instead of vw ***/
  margin: 4vh auto 4vh;
  padding: 2vh 5vh 2vh;

  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.bio-pic {
  float: left;
  margin: 2vh 2vh 1vh;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.container h2 {
  margin-top: 2vh;
}

.container p {
  margin-left: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container' id='about'>
    <Image class='bio-pic' src={profile} alt='casey' />
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>
      I am a full-stack web developer, passionate about turning ideas into
      reality. Experienced with front-end and back-end development, I enjoy
      the logical puzzles that come with software engineering and take pride
      in writting elegant, dry code. I am excited to apply the skills I've
      built as a developer in a challenging environment where I can grow as
      a professional and be a positive impact as a team member.
      <br />
      <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
      aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
      pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
      culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give widths in `vh` (viewport-height) units. Hence when your screen width changes, width of `container` is not changed as it is dependent on height of the screen.

Try to change `vh` to `vw` (viewport-width) like so :-

```css
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 4vh auto 4vh;
  padding: 2vh 5vh 2vh;

  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

**PS:-**

Just wanted to mention that you are using `vh` at many places in your `css` for setting `margins` and `paddings`. I think you should use `ems`.